# how to reset a common ldap user's password in python without old password?

Tags: python, ldap

I use python2, below is my code:

```
import ldap
LDAP_HOST = 'ldap://192.168.3.3'
USER = 'cn=admin,dc=node1,dc=com' #admin DN
PASSWORD = 'secret' #admin passwd
BASE_DN = 'dc=node1,dc=com'
conn = ldap.initialize(LDAP_HOST)
conn.simple_bind_s(USER, PASSWORD)
```

the DN need reset his password is `uid=test,ou=People,dc=node1,dc=com`,
I know with linux bash `ldappasswd -x -D "cn=admin,dc=node1,dc=com" -w secret -s 555 "uid=test,ou=People,dc=node1,dc=com"` I can reset the password to `555`, but how with python-ldap.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out a simple way to solve this, below is the code:

```
# login as admin user
import ldap
from ldap import modlist
LDAP_HOST = 'ldap://192.168.3.3'
USER = 'cn=admin,dc=node1,dc=com' #admin DN
PASSWORD = 'secret' #admin passwd
BASE_DN = 'dc=node1,dc=com'
conn = ldap.initialize(LDAP_HOST)
conn.simple_bind_s(USER, PASSWORD)

# change the password
tdn="uid=test,ou=People,dc=node1,dc=com")
mod_attrs = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE,"userPassword","444"),]
conn.modify_s(tdn,mod_attrs)
```

Comment: could you elaborate on this abit? in the `mod_attrs` variable. Could you explain those values?

Comment: you can see more details at [official site](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/python-ldap-applications-extra-ldap-operations-and-ldap-url-library), the `mod_attrs` is just a python list type that the ldap method `modify_s` can use,  you can also see the [ldap3 modify method](http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/tutorial_operations.html#what-s-next), Ldap3 is more powerfully I think.